# Difference between application cache and object cache

Tags: caching

I'm reading Martin L. Abbott, Michael T. Fisher's Scalability rules: 50 principles for scaling Web sites, and in rules 24 and 25 they talk about Application Caches and Object Caches respectively.

My previous understanding was that an Application Cache, let's say ehCache, it's a layer that you put between your services and your DB, where you put objects in order to avoid hitting the DB for objects previously queried (and still valid). But know I'm not sure.

Can somebody explain what is the difference between the two, if possible with an example?